# How to export a project in UIMA

Tags: uima

I have a java annotator and now I want to use it in UIMA.
I followed the guide to make a new annotator in UIMA and now I do not know where to put my JAVA code, which folders to put my files and how they relate to the XML file.
  I am stuck.
Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

first follow these steps:

1, Defining Types

2. Generating Java Source Files for CAS Types
3. Developing Your Annotator Code
4. Creating the XML Descriptor
5. Testing Your Annotator

   and 4th point is your required answer after creating java annotator code